# Arch Linux Java critical error executing jar

Tags: java, archlinux

If I try to run my .jar file with `java -jar SG.jar` I get the following error message:

```
java:2285): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 16:58:47.463: gdk_x11_display_set_window_scale: assertion 'GDK_IS_X11_DISPLAY (display)' failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f01d2eec673, pid=2285, tid=2321
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (13.0.2+8) (build 13.0.2+8)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (13.0.2+8, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libX11.so.6+0x2b673]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to run a JavaFX application under Wayland, try starting the app as `java -Djdk.gtk.version=2 -jar SG.jar` as per [this](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/175#issuecomment-417030981) comment.